# Ensuring a call method at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I ensure that a specific method is called, at compile time?

For example, suppose I have an object with 2 methods:

```
struct Foo
{
   ... func1(...);
   ... func2(...);
};
```

and I want to ensure that func1 is called before any calls to func2, i.e.:

```
int main()
{
   Foo f;
   ...
   f.func1(...);
   f.func2(...);
   f.func2(...); // and so on
}
```

but I want to generate a compile error if I do something like that:

```
int main()
{
   Foo f;
   ...
   f.func2(...);  // generate a compile error due the fact that func1 must be called first
   f.func1(...);
   f.func2(...); // and so on
}
```

Comment: You can try using `constexpr`, but it won't work in that case. (Is not guaranteed to work in any case really).

Comment: I guess this can be done only with code analyzers. The compiler itself can only warn you about an unused function - AFAIK.

Comment: If you need to do this probably you should keep thinking for a better class design. This is a squential coupling antipattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling

Answer (score 11):

While curious why would you do this, general note is that you must ***expose to user an interface that cannot be used wrong***. Guts go private:

```
struct Foo
{
public:
    void callme()
    {
        func1();
        func2();
    }

private:
    ... func1(...);
    ... func2(...);


};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.callme();
}
```

If you need to enforce one time initialization of objects, do it in constructor:

```
struct Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        func1();
    }

    func2(...);
private:
    ... func1(...);
};

int main()
{
    Foo f; // func1() called automagically
    f.func2();
}
```

Designing class interfaces, you must allways think about the worst things: users never read documentation, users always forget to call `foo.initialize()`, users always forget freeing memory and it leaks, etc.

Comment: I'd also mention that you can pass arguments from `callme` to `func1...funcn` by using `std::forward`. With enough determination, you could create the signature of `callme` automatically from the list of the functions it's supposed to use, making it more transparent.

Comment: You have asked me why I wanna this. Take a look at this article (http://www.di.unipi.it/~nids/docs/templates_vs_inheritance.html). Here, when you do a strategy pattern (not sure if it is really a strategy pattern) using templates, you initialize object, not by constructor, but calling an init function. I want to make sure that the user has done this, but at compile time.

Comment: @TomásBadan I don't see any need in `init()` methods in this example. In fact, they *can* be replaced by constructors. So, no matter where and who would previously call `init()`, will now simply pass arguments to a constructor or to a factory (which passes them to constructor).

Comment: @Drop As said in that text: "(...) The writer classes implement ... the init method ... to make the initialization of the objects ... because we define them as base classes for the logger and this one cannot have the "constructors" for all the possible super classes. (...)". So, even if the init arguments are passed to base constructor, the question is, the user thas to call init to initialize the base objects, otherwise, they will problably be initialized by default constructors.

Comment: @TomásBadan We can really have constructors with any combinations of parameters in base class (variadic template magic). And there are other solutions too. By the way, pattern described in this article has nothing common with "strategy". It is called [Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). But this question isn't related to enforcing an order of function calls. Due to SO rules, you must open another topic to discuss it.

Comment: While this is generally good advice, it doesn't answer the question that was asked -- how to find problems of this type at *compile time*.

Answer (score 5):

There is no real way to enforce this at compilation time.  This is something that the object itself will need to enforce with runtime checks

Answer (score 3):

One method that comes to mind, is to let return func1() an object, that acts like a proxy to func2():

```
class Foo {
public:
    Proxy func1();   
private:
    void func2();
    friend class Proxy;
};

class Proxy {
private:
    explicit Proxy(Foo& f) : f_(f) {}
public:
    void func2() {
        f_.func2();
    }
    friend class Foo;
};

Foo f;
f.func1().func2();
```

An other method (and my favorite) is to let func1() be a constructor or to use an other class, that calls func1() in it's constructor:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    void func1(), func2();
    friend class FooUser;
};

class FooUser
{
public:
    explicit Proxy(FooUser& f) : f_(f) {
        f.func1();
    }

    void func2() {
        f_.func2();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can't enforce the order of function calls, since in general that can only be determined at run-time. But it can enforce object initialisation before the object can be used. So the best way to get a compile-time check is to do whatever `func1` does in a constructor - either part of `Foo`'s constructor, or a helper object that you need to create in order to call `func2`.

Answer (score 1):

I really do not suggest to do so, but if you need it for debugging purposes you can try following.
Change every call func1() to

```
#define FLAG
func1();
```

and func2() to

```
#ifdef FLAG
func2();
#else
#error func1 should be called first!
#endif
```

So you will receive a compile-time error if func2() will be mentioned upper in text then func1. It does not mean it will be really called earlier during execution.